# List all $n \le 40$ such that $n \ne a^2-b^2$ for $a,b,n \in Z^+$

Tags: number-theory

List in increasing order all positive integers $n \le 40$ such that n cannot be written in the
form $a^2-b^2$, where a and b are positive integers.

My approach is to find all n=$a^2-b^2$, which gives the condition that $b^2 \le a^2 \le b^2+40$

Now, we can take perfect squares from $b^2$ to $b^2+40$ as $a^2$, and subsequently get n. But, it doesn't look all that beautiful. I am looking for a beautiful solution to the problem.

Comment: $n\not\equiv2\pmod4$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner OP wants the ones that **cannot** be written in this form, so $n \equiv 2 (\text{mod} 4)$.

Comment: If $n>1$ is an odd integer, then $$n=\left(\dfrac{n+1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{n-1}{2}\right)^2\,.$$  If $n>4$ is an integer divisible by $4$, then $$n=\left(\dfrac{n}{4}+1\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{n}{4}-1\right)^2\,.$$

Comment: Beautiful or not, what did you obtain as a solution? Consider these numbers modulo $4$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael:  of course you are correct; I regret that I commented before reading OP carefully enough

Answer (score 1):

The hints and answers thus far tell you that numbers of the form $4k+2$ cannot be written as the difference of two squares. This would afford the list $2,6,10,\dots,38$ as numbers that cannot be written as the difference of two squares. However, you must take into account that the only ways to write $1$ and $4$ as the difference of two squares is $1^2-0^2=1;\ 2^2-0^2=4$. Since $0$ is not in $\mathbb N^+$ (as you require), you must include $1,4$ in your list as well.

Answer (score 0):

As $a+b\pm(a-b)$ is even, so $a+b,a-b$ have the same parity

If $n$ is odd, trivially $a-b=1,a+b=n$

If $(a-b)(a+b)=n$ is even

one of $a+b,a-b$ must be even, hence both must be even

So, if $n$ is even, $4$ must divide $n$